# How to create a point type variable in java?

Tags: java, variables, point

I am trying to plot co-ordinates in variables. I am using the `Point` class and can not find a simple way to iterate the variables.

To plot a point of (0,0), I try the following code,

```
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args){
    point p = new  Point();
  }
}
```

and get an error saying it can't find the symbol Point.
(for some reason it can't find the symbol point at the start too, but I thought that was just declaring the name of the variable?)
Do you have to put something before this to make it work?

Comment: `import java.awt.Point` at the beginning of the file, if that's the actual `Point` class you want to use

Comment: Here you go https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ your syntax is all wrong, so if you ever want to get any `Point`s going, you'll have to study a bit (a lot) first.

Comment: @Federico klez Culloca thanks, this fixed the error in finding the Point symbol, but what about the error saying there's a problem with the variable name 'point'?

Comment: @MaltedWheaties there's no variable named point. There's a variable named `p` and a misspelled type named `point`.

Comment: Did you search for _cannot find symbol_? If you did, did you not see: [What does a “Cannot find symbol” or “Cannot resolve symbol” error mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25706216/what-does-a-cannot-find-symbol-or-cannot-resolve-symbol-error-mean)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the import statement for the Point class, and use capital "P" in point.

```java
import java.awt.Point;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Point p = new Point();   //--> Note 'P' in Point is capital case on each side of =
    }
}
```